# Java Error scanning JSONObject program using scanner scans infinitely

Tags: java, json, parsing, jsonparser

I get this error on writing this program, i was wanting to just pass through the scanner to the JSONobject an print the json object

But the scanner goes in infinite loop

```
package com.readvalues.main;

import java.util.Scanner;
import net.sf.json.JSONObject;

public class ReadValues 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String x="";
        try 
        {   
            System.out.println("Enter the data");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            while(scanner.hasNext())
            {
                x = x + scanner.next();
            }

            JSONObject jsonObject = JSONObject.fromObject(x);
            System.out.println(jsonObject);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

IN THE TERMINAL

```
Enter the data
{"ExecutiveGoal":
{"EMPLID":"100020","GOAL_ID":"GOAL-3-98372","GOAL":"Conduct EPC Contract Kaizen","DUE_DATE":"07/01/2018","STATUS":"On Track or Complete (Green)","CATEGORY":"Operational Goal","SUPPORTS_ORG_GOAL":"","COMPLETED_ON":"06/30/2018","CREATED_BY":"Mark Hensley","CREATED_ON":"03/01/2018","LAST_UPDATED_BY":"Mark Hensley","LAST_UPDATED_ON":"03/01/2018"
},
"ExecutiveGoal":
{"EMPLID":"100020","GOAL_ID":"GOAL-3-98373","GOAL":"Exit 2018 with minimum 5 negotiators trained and capable in O&M, MSAs, EPCs, and MIPSAs. At least 2 negotiators capable in PPAs.","DUE_DATE":"12/31/2018","STATUS":"On Track or Complete (Green)","CATEGORY":"People Leader Goal","SUPPORTS_ORG_GOAL":"","COMPLETED_ON":"","CREATED_BY":"Mark Hensley","CREATED_ON":"03/01/2018","LAST_UPDATED_BY":"Mark Hensley","LAST_UPDATED_ON":"03/01/2018"
}
}
//INFINITE LOOP SCANNING
```

I've tried everyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `scanner.nextInt()` it waits for integer value. You are inputting a json string and that's why it complains. You need to change that to `scanner.next()` that expects a string.

Also your loop written like that will never end. It will require you to read strings from input forever. You might consider some "exit" condition ;)

Comment: That was a mistake for the program i typed there, i actually used 
scanner.next()

Comment: The loop will never end because you haven't told it when to end. A common scenario would be for example to check for some string and when that is inputted to end the loop

Answer (score 1):

Scanner is waiting for int...
scanner.nextLine() would be help.

Comment: That was a mistake for the program i typed there, i actually used 
scanner.next()